# flex skins or style?

Tags: apache-flex, customization, flex4.5, skinning, flex-spark

I made a research, but I didn't find anything to helps me answer this question

When you have a flex project, is it better to use different skins for different components or to use just one big css that has all the styles together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very clear from the question are you talking about standard components and their custom skins/styles or you're talking about custom components and ways to design them to be customizable?

Anyway I'll try to answer. Spark architecture isn't reject styles and using CSS for component's customization. All the standard components support styles and have out-of-the-box skins which support them. So if you're using standard components with standard skins and it fits your requirements it is better to use available styles for additional customization.

If standard skins of standard components don't fit your needs you have to decide which strategy to choose:

1. Create skins which support additional customization with CSS. You can choose this option if you're creating some skins for external use (for some other developers or teams). It gives them possibility to use your skins without modification and with additional customization. If you're creating custom components for sale or for a client you also should choose this strategy.
2. Create skins without additional customization possibilities (all the values such as colors, icons, fills, strokes, fonts are hardcoded). This is the easiest way to create skins. And it allows you to perform skin's modifications easily. You should choose this options if you're creating skins for the particular project with particular look and feel. The main advantage is you can create and modify skins very simple and fast with more flexible usage of external tools such as Flash Catalyst.

Comment: I'm talking about using custom components with each one of them having their own design, for example, if I have a custom button, and I want to have a different color for each state of the button, would it be better to use a skin to do that, or just some css will do?

Comment: If state is external (for example "okState", "cancelState", "applyState") which should change button appearance, the best way to implement it is using button skin which supported styles and change appearance with styles. The rule is pretty simple. Skin is view and component is model and controller. If some mutable functionality is only related to component's view (but not its logic) — styles is the best way to implement it. If it is related to logic (model for example) — it is better to change skin itself.